# HTML: Conditional submission of hidden input without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

If I have a simple html form with two submit buttons:

```
<form method="POST" class="submit_form main_form" action="myaction">
    <input type="submit" name="goback" value="Go Back"  />
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
    <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="hello"/>
</form>
```

It is possible to only post the hidden input if the "confirm" submit is clicked?

If the "goback" submit is clicked the hidden input should be ignored.  I know how to accomplish this with JavaScript but was wondering if it can be done with just html.

For anyone wondering, this is how you do this in JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('submit_form');
    elements[0].addEventListener(
        'submit', 
        function(event) {
            if(event.explicitOriginalTarget.name === 'goback'){
                var hiddenInput = document.querySelector("input[name='step']");
                hiddenInput.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: if you really want that, create an event on confirm's click, append a field and then submit the form.

Comment: Do you need to send any other data, just exclude secret? Or do you just want to go to another page without sending anything?

Pure html solution is having a link, that you can style to look as a button and it simply redirect you without submission.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I want to do this without JS if possible.

Comment: @smartilabs there is more to the form than that, this is just a basic example to see if this is actually possible. It would still need to submit some other input data.

Comment: PHP runs on the server when the form is being created, it's not in the loop when the user is filling in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the buttons in 2 separate forms:

```
<form method="POST" class="submit_form main_form" action="myaction">
    <input type="submit" name="goback" value="Go Back"  />
</form>
<form method="POST" class="submit_form main_form" action="myaction">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
    <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="hello"/>
</form>
```

That way the secret field will only be posted if the confirm button is clicked.

If you want to do it in the php code you can leave your form as is
and check if `isset($_POST["confirm"])` to check if the confirm button was the one clicked.

Comment: I think this might be the best solution if there are no other non JS solutions. Obviously requires extra styling though.